# Trouble getting a valid token in Web Api 2, even after Cors is enabled

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So I've installed the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.5.2.3` in my VS2015 solution, and also have enabled CORS in my Web Api project.

I have successfully used Fidder to test my `/token` POST request, and my GET request to API controller `\api\values`.

If I use the token I received back in Fiddler, and hard code it into my JavaScript GET request - I can indeed make a successful request to `\api\values` from my Single Page Application.

PROBLEM: I cannot make a successful POST request to `http://localhost:17883/token` in my local dev environment.

The error in Chrome is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:17883//token.
Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:17883//token".
```

I've enabled CORS in WebApiConfig.cs -

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace API
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // *** ENABLE CORS ***
            var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

In my Angular `authService`, I coded up an API test function hooked up to a button on my `Login` page (this request is successful):

```js
var _apitest = function ()
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var tkn='cbJZpiF-rEdi_WgWzuFOAxPZ0lBiqivEnOmpSYMPu_fuvu37cpLFzHhzc119GfwIc6dnDivYhhH2a1O2bMa6EExRGa3lvPfzZJHiDDaH6klIU2NFEG5FMxFl_-Z_jBQvPkPyW_31iP6P_oVNZZpXzkQfkwA4zilzKLE7If2Dko6MNNID1lscVfkZ4emJXWpalSXCS4A7qmO-ceIchMfrcbZHgVqBjZC_YHz-DxAfg2lTksUdn8NBir_cDOH5Ymsrzj_bKP1H6WJULDfZEPuh0PpB2DlJEXOV63KWUf7Eubp_FYfni5czD1Z-lh2a2RPRfpRxlMQVBUCCp03_Ul5a6lzOFHSJCJlynidw2DV_InK-oFZEuvQK2Xiy_7wq0JVmx-Nej1bQRN7b2eWK25jjdrTfCNyMdtmDZ7qOSmX3dWuyQhCbp_15ciFhmr7wfIYPzsFssbg-XHtDi2lw87KkJ0IhNmtnsoNyKCrM5ibJG5O5t_gxr3l52JN54Jj2mbeY';

        var req={
            "method": "GET",            
            "url": "http://localhost:17883/api/values",
            "headers": {                
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + tkn
            }
        };        
        $http(req).then(function (data)
        {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

This POST request to `\token` is NOT successful:

```js
var _loginUserPost = function (loginData)
    {        
        var controllerpath = "/token";    
        var url = serviceBase + controllerpath;
        var body = "username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password + "&grant_type=password";
        
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.notify("Logging in user...");

        // POST REQUEST !!
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            encoding: 'JSON',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application;x-www-form-urlencoded'                
            },
            url: url,
            data: body 
        };

        $http(req).then(function (data)
        {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }, function (err)
        {
            deferred.reject("Failed to login user via api call.");
            console.log("Failed to login user via api call. Errors details: " + err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

I also tried to decorate the `ApplicationOAuthProvide` class with the `EnableCors` attribute, but it still doesn't work:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
     ...
}
```

I really need to know what I'm missing. I have been searching and trying different things - but to no avail.

Advice is appreciated.

Bob

********* UPDATE - What I've tried so far ************

Still, request to `\token` is kicked back with CORS exception in Chrome.

I've tried unsuccessfully to add `Headers` (search "Step 10:" in this article: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ ):

```
   public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });   // BM:

    ...
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an Options() Action in your controller. It's probably making a preflight Options request before the post and not finding a matching action.

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

Depending on how IIS is configured, you may also need to allow the options request in your web.config

```cs
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs applyToWebDAV="false">
          <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true" />         
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
<system.webServer>
```

Also make sure the Content-Type you're specifying in Angular is the same as what's being expected by Web Api

```cs
var req = {
    // ...
    headers: 
        'Content-Type': 'application;x-www-form-urlencoded'                
    },
    // ..
};
```

Comment: I'm trying it now, but the Get request to `\api\values` controller does work fine. It's the initial request to `\token` that doesn't work. Is it something in `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class ?

Comment: I tried this answer, but I'm not sure it's hitting the `MatchEndpoint` method - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932286/cors-works-for-access-token-but-not-for-refresh-token-in-web-api-2

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? You may also need to update your web.config to allow Options (I'll update my answer with an example)

Comment: error is in post above. `Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: Sorry, blew right over. Also make sure that the Content-Type you're sending is the same that Web Api is expecting.

Comment: Nothing makes a different. `applyToWebDAV="false"` is saying that the attribute is not allowed. I've added that to my Web Api project's web.config as suggested.